# How to write output to the statusBar next to specific label in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a notepad like application in Qt Creator and I want to have a text statistics written to the statusBar (fe. word, character count). In a form of **"words: 14 characters: 80"**

Currently I'm able to display the number of words as int with:

```
ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString::number(counter));
```

but when I wanted to add a label "words:" before the counter with:

```
ui->statusBar->addPermanentWidget(ui->label1, 1);
```

it ignores the counter and the label shows "above" it, hiding the counter.

The goal is to have 4 kinds of counters in the statusBar.
I'm currently looking for a widget that would allow me to print a static string like "words: " and a counter next to it.

Comment: You can call `setText` on label, `label1->setText(QString("words: %1").arg(123));`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the widget support in the QStatus bar, but do you need to do more than just format the string you're trying to display?

```
ui->statusBar->showMessage ("words: %1 characters: %2").arg (counter).arg (char_counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some conceptual problems here.

If you set a QWidget to be a permanent widget within the QStatusBar, it will usually show on the far right side of the statusbar. A temporary message (like the one you want to display using showMessage()) will never be shown above it. Usually that's not a problem, since the permanent widgets are shown on the far right side, and temporary messages are shown on the far left side.

Here's the kicker, you added a stretch factor to your permanent label widget:

```
ui->statusBar->addPermanentWidget(ui->label1, 1);
```

I mean the "*1*" you used as a second parameter. Lose it. You don't need it. But you still won't be satisfied with your result, since it will look like this:

[image: Screenshot1]

What you want is something like this, I assume:

[image]

You have several options to accomplish this:

1. The counter is an own widget itself and is added permanently to the status bar like the "Words:" label after it.
2. You display the counter as part of the words label, using QString::arg() for example.
3. You create QLabel subclass that displays the static text followed by the counter with a nice setter method to change the word count. This is basically option #2 but a bit more luxurious.

Probably there are more things you could do but those should get you on the right track.

### Code examples

#### 1

In the *slot* that gets called each time the count changes you do this:

```
// Assuming that 'wordCount' contains the current word count:
ui->label1->setText( QString( "Words: %1" ).arg( wordCount );
```

#### 2

```
// In your setup code:
QLabel* wordsLabel = new QLabel( QString( "Words:" ) );
m_wordCountLabel = new QLabel( QString::number( 0 ) ); // initial

statusBar()->addPermanentWidget( wordsLabel );
statusBar()->addPermanentWidget( m_wordCountLabel );

// Inside your update word count slot:
m_wordCountLabel->setText( QString::number( wordCount ) );
```

#### 3

```
// In your setup code
m_wordCountIndicator = new MyWordCountIndicator;
statusBar()->addPermanentWidget( m_wordCountIndicator );

// Inside your update word count slot:
m_wordCountIndicator->setWordCount( wordCount );
```

In this approach you could actually give your **WordCountIndicator**, which basically subclasses *QLabel* a Slot to change the text. Now you could directly connect it to a signal that gets emitted everytime the word count changes (if you have such a thing). As stated before, there are several approaches, each with its pros and cons.

P.S.: I've notived you're "abusing" the UI file to create your label to display in the QStatusBar. That is somewhat bad practice. It still works, the moment you set the widget as a permanent widget in the status bar, it will be reparented to the QStatusBar instance. In your case I would humbly suggest creating your indicator labels directly in your code.